# Copy and paste text from webpage to txt file or csv file

Tags: python, web-scraping, error-handling

I am trying to copy text from a webpage and paste it into a text file. Nothing too fancy but I can't seem to figure out how to do it or find anything online that works.

```
import requests

url = 'https://seekingalpha.com/article/4166013-t-t-q1-2018-results-earnings-call-transcript?part=single'
data = requests.get(url)

with open('file.txt','w') as out_f:
   out_f.write(data.text)
```

I get a unicode encode error, \ufeff. Is there a way to just select all, copy, and then paste into a text file? Seems so simple but can't figure it out.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding your text as utf-8

```
import requests

url = 'https://seekingalpha.com/article/4166013-t-t-q1-2018-results-earnings-call-transcript?part=single'
data = requests.get(url)

with open('file.txt','w') as out_f:
   out_f.write(data.text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I had to put data.text.encode in str() because it was saying that write() argument had to be a str and not a byte, but otherwise that fixed the issue!

One follow up, the text that I am pulling has a lot of HTML. I'm still fairly new @ python but from some quick googling, I am supposed to use BeautifulSoup to parse the text?

Comment: BeautifulSoup isn't a HTML parser, it works with some python html parse libraries. It's a html dom utility. If you want to work with html is the fastest and easiest way.