# How to copy all text of web page from website link using Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to access DNA sequences at a specific part but it is too many of them but I saw a pattern of the URL link like this

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/**AF193276.1**?report=fasta&log$=seqview&format=text&from=**1311**&to=**4322**

this link, I can access DNA sequences of HIV (ID:AF193276.1) from position 1311 to 4322 below.

```
>AF193276.1:1311-4322 HIV-1 CRF03_AB isolate KAL153 from Russia, complete genome
TTTTTTAGGGAGAATTTGGCCTTCCAGCAAAGGGAGGCCAGGAAATTTTCCTCAGAGCAGACCAGAGCCA
TCAGCCCCACCAGCAGAAAACTTTGGGATGGGGGAAGAGATAACCCCCTCCCTGAAACAGGAACAGAAGG
ACAGGGAACAGCATCCTCCTTCAATTTCCCTCAAATCACTCTTTGGCGACGACCCCTTGTCACAGTAAGA
ATAGGAGGACAGCTAAAAGAAGCTCTATTAGATACAGGAGCAGATGATACAGTATTAGAAGACATAAATT
TGCCAGGAAAATGGAAACCAAAAATGATAGGGGGGATTGGAGGTTTTATCAAGGTAAGACAGTATGATCA
GATACTTATAGAAATTTGTGGAAAAAAGGCTATAGGTACGGTATTAGTAGGACCTACCCCTGTCAACATA
ATTGGAAGAAATATGTTGACTCAGCTTGGTTGTACTTTAAATTTTCCAATAAGTCCTATTGAAACTGTAC
CAGTAACATTAAAGCCAGGAATGGATGGCCCAAAGGTTAAACAATGGCCATTAACAGAAGAGAAAATAAA
AGCATTAACAGACATTTGTAAGGAGATGGAAAAGGAAGGAAAAATTTCAAAAATTGGGCCTGAAAATCCA
TACAATACTCCAGTATTTGCCATAAAGAAAAAAGACAGTACTAAATGGAGAAAATTAGTAGGTTTCAGAG
AACTTAATAAGAGAACTCAAGACTTCTGGGAAGTTCAATTAGGAATACCACACCCTGCAGGGTTAAAAAA
GAAAAAATCTGTAACAGTACTGGATGTGGGTGATGCATATTTTTCAGTTCCCTTAGATCAAGACTTCAGA
AAGTATACTGCATTTACCATACCTAGTACAAACAATGAGACACCAGGGATTAGATATCAGTACAATGTGC
TTCCACAGGGATGGAAAGGATCACCAGCAATTTTCCAAAGTAGCATGACAAAAATCTTAGAGCCTTTTAG
AAAACAAAATCCAGAGATAGTTATCTATCAATACATGGATGATTTGTATGTAGGATCTGACTTAGAGATA
GGGCAGCATAGAACAGAAATAGAGGAACTGAGAGAACATCTGCTGAGGTGGGGATTTACCACACCAGACA
AAAAACATCAGAAAGAACCTCCATTCCTTTGGATGGGTTATGAACTCCATCCTGATAAATGGACTGTACA
GCCTATAGTGTTGCCAGAAAAAGACAGCTGGACTGTCAATGACATACAGAAGCTAGTGGGAAAATTGAAT
TGGGCAAGTCAGATTTATGCAGGGATTAAAGTAAGGCAATTATGTAAACTCCTTAGGGGAGCCAAAGCAC
TAACAGAAGTAATACCACTAACAGCAGAAGCAGAGCTAGAACTGGCAGAAAACAGGGAGATTCTAAAAGA
ACCAGTACATGGAGTGTATTATGACCCATCAAAAGACTTAGTAGCAGAAATACAGAAGCAGGGACAAGGC
CAATGGACATATCAAATTTATCAAGAGCCATTTAAAAATCTGAAAACAGGAAAATATGCAAGACTGAGGG
GTGCCCACACTAATGACGTAAAACAGTTAACAGAGGCAGTGCAAAAAATAGCCACTGAAAGCATAGTAAT
ATGGGGAAAGACTCCTAAATTTAAACTACCCATACAAAAAGAAACATGGGAAACATGGTGGACAGAGTAT
TGGCAAGCCACCTGGATTCCTGAGTGGGAATTTGTCAATACCCCTCCCTTAGTAAAATTATGGTACCAGT
TAGAGAAAGAACCCATAGTAGGAGCAGAAACTTTCTATGTAGATGGAGCAGCTAATAGGGAGACTAAATC
AGGAAAAGCAGGATATGTTACTGACAGAGGAAGACAAAAGGTTGTCTCCCTAACTGACACAACAAATCAG
AAGACTGAGTTACAAGCAATTCATCTAGCTTTGCAGGATTCGGGATTAGAAGTAAACATAGTAACAGACT
CACAATATGCATTAGGAATCATTCAAGCACAACCAGATAAGAGTGAATCAGAGTTAGTCAGTCAAATAAT
AGAGCAGTTGATAAAAAAGGAAAAGGTCTACCTGGCATGGGTACCAGCACACAAAGGAATTGGAGGAAAT
GAACAAGTTGATAAATTAGTCAGTGCTGGAATCAGGGAAGTACTATTTTTAGATGGAATAGATAAGGCAC
AAGAAGAACATGAGAAATATCACGGTAATTGGAGAGCAATGGCTAGTGATTTTAACCTGCCACCTGTGGT
AGCAAAAGAAATAGTAGCCAGCTGTGATAAATGTCAATTAAAAGGAGAAGCCATGCACGGACAAGTAGAC
TGTAGTCCAGGAATATGGCAACTAGATTGTACACATTTAGAAGGAAAAATTATCCTAGTAGCAGTTCATG
TAGCCAGTGGATATATAGAAGCAGAAGTTATTCCAGCAGAAACAGGACAGGAAACAGCATACTTTGTCTT
AAAATTAGCAGGAAGATGGCCAGTAAAAATAATACATACAGACAATGGCAGCAATTTCACCAGTACTGCG
GTTAAGGCTGCCTGTTGGTGGGCAGGGATCAAGCAGGAATTTGGCATTCCCTACAATCCCCAAAGTCAAG
GAGTAGTAGAATCTATGAATAAACAATTAAAGCAAACTATAGGACAGGTAAGAGATCAAGCTGAACATCT
TAAGACAGCAGTACAAATGGCAGTATTCATCCACAATTTTAAAAGAAAAGGGGGGATTGGGGGGTACAGT
GCAGGGGAAAGAATAATAGACATAATAGCAACAGACATACAAACTAAAGAATTACAAAAACAAATTATAA
AAATTCAAAATTTTCGGGTTTATTACAGAGACAGCAGAGATCCAATTTGGAAAGGACCAGCAAAACTACT
CTGGAAAGGTGAAGGGGCAGTGGTAATACAGGACAATAACGATATAAAAGTAGTACCAAGAAGAAAAGCA
AAGATCATTAGGGATTATGGAAAACAGATGGCAGGTGATGATTGTGTGGCAAGTAGACAGGATGAGGATT
AG
```

I need all information on this webpage but for several strains.

If I change strain ID and DNA position, I think I can copy all of those DNA sequences.

I try this from [Copy and paste text from webpage to txt file or csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51276197/copy-and-paste-text-from-webpage-to-txt-file-or-csv-file/51276234)

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AF061641.1?report=fasta&log$=seqview&format=text&from=192&to=1684'
data = requests.get(url)
with open('file.txt','w') as out_f:
   out_f.write(str(data.text.encode('utf-8')))
```

but I got this instead

```
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">\n<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\n    <head xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />\n    <!-- meta -->\n    <meta name="robots" content="index,nofollow,noarchive" />\n<meta name="ncbi_app" content="entrez" /><meta name="ncbi_db" content="nuccore" /><meta name="ncbi_report" content="fasta" /><meta name="ncbi_format" content="text" /><meta name="ncbi_pagesize" content="20" /><meta name="ncbi_sortorder" content="default" /><meta name="ncbi_pageno" content="1" /><meta name="ncbi_resultcount" content="1" /><meta name="ncbi_op" content="retrieve" /><meta name="ncbi_pdid" content="fasta" /><meta name="ncbi_sessionid" content="CE8C1A31EBE79081_2023SID" /><meta name="ncbi_uidlist" content="3403216" /><meta name="ncbi_filter" content="all" /><meta name="ncbi_stat" content="false" /><meta name="ncbi_hitstat" content="false" />\n\n    \n    <!-- title -->\n    <title>HIV-1 isolate HH8793 clone 12.1 from Finland, complete genome - Nucleotide - NCBI</title>\n    \n    <!-- Common JS and CSS -->\n    \n\t\t<script type="text/javascript">\n\t\t    var ncbi_startTime = new Date();\n\t\t</script>\n\t\t<style>.async-hide { opacity: 0 !important} </style><script type="text/javascript" src="/core/assets/kis/dist/kis_ga_nuc_protein.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.pubmed.gov/core/jig/1.14.8/js/jig.min.js"></script>\n\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t<script type="text/javascript" src="/core/ajax_loader/2.1/js/loadingbar.js"></script> \n        \t<script type="text/javascript" src="/core/ajax_loader/2.1/js/contentLoader.js"></script>\n        \t<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/core/ajax_loader/2.1/css/loadingbar.css" />\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t  \n    \n    <link xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//static.pubmed.gov/portal/portal3rc.fcgi/4187342/css/3881636/3579733.css" xml:base="http://127.0.0.1/sites/static/header_footer/" />    \n<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/favicon.ico" /><meta name="ncbi_phid" content="CE8C1A31EBE6A9A10000000007E703EB.m_11" /><script type="text/javascript"><!--\nvar ScriptPath = \'/portal/\';\nvar objHierarchy = {"name":"EntrezSystem2","type":"Layout","realname":"EntrezSystem2",\n"children":[{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez","type":"Cluster","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez",\n"children":[{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.DbConnector","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PEntrez.DbConnector","shortname":"DbConnector"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.ParamContainer","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PEntrez.ParamContainer","shortname":"ParamContainer"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.MyNcbi","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PEntrez.MyNcbi","shortname":"MyNcbi"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.UserPreferenceUrlParamContainer","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PEntrez.UserPreferenceUrlParamContainer","shortname":"UserPreferenceUrlParamContainer"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.GridProperty","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.PEntrez.GridProperty","shortname":"GridProperty"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore","type":"Cluster","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore",\n"children":[{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.NoPortlet","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Entrez_Database.NoPortlet","shortname":"NoPortlet"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_PageController","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Sequence_PageController","shortname":"Sequence_PageController"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Entrez_SearchBar","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Entrez_Database.Entrez_SearchBar","shortname":"Entrez_SearchBar"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Entrez_BotRequest","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Entrez_Database.Entrez_BotRequest","shortname":"Entrez_BotRequest"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_LimitsTab","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Sequence_LimitsTab","shortname":"Sequence_LimitsTab"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel","type":"Cluster","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Sequence_ResultsPanel",\n"children":[{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.blankToolPanel","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Sequence_ResultsPanel.Entrez_ResultsPanel.blankToolPanel","shortname":"blankToolPanel"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.Sequence_ResultsController","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Sequence_ResultsPanel.Sequence_ResultsController","shortname":"Sequence_ResultsController"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Filters","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Sequence_ResultsPanel.Entrez_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Filters","shortname":"Entrez_Filters"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Sequence_ResultsPanel.Entrez_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Pager","shortname":"Entrez_Pager"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.Sequence_DisplayBar","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Sequence_ResultsPanel.Sequence_DisplayBar","shortname":"Sequence_DisplayBar"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.HelpFormAttributes","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Sequence_ResultsPanel.Entrez_ResultsPanel.HelpFormAttributes","shortname":"HelpFormAttributes"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Collections","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Sequence_ResultsPanel.Entrez_ResultsPanel.Entrez_Collections","shortname":"Entrez_Collections"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SpellCheck","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Sequence_ResultsPanel.Entrez_ResultsPanel.SpellCheck","shortname":"SpellCheck"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SearchEngineReferralCheck","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Sequence_ResultsPanel.Entrez_ResultsPanel.SearchEngineReferralCheck","shortname":"SearchEngineReferralCheck"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.KnowledgePanel","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Sequence_ResultsPanel.Entrez_ResultsPanel.KnowledgePanel","shortname":"KnowledgePanel"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.HistoryDisplay","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Sequence_ResultsPanel.Entrez_ResultsPanel.HistoryDisplay","shortname":"HistoryDisplay"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.Discovery_SearchDetails","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Sequence_ResultsPanel.Entrez_ResultsPanel.Discovery_SearchDetails","shortname":"Discovery_SearchDetails"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.KISSensor","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Sequence_ResultsPanel.KISSensor","shortname":"KISSensor"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.MultiSensorPortlet","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Sequence_ResultsPanel.MultiSensorPortlet","shortname":"MultiSensorPortlet"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.WrongDbSensor","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Sequence_ResultsPanel.WrongDbSensor","shortname":"WrongDbSensor"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.Sequence_DiscoveryExptChooser","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Sequence_ResultsPanel.Sequence_DiscoveryExptChooser","shortname":"Sequence_DiscoveryExptChooser"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SequenceViewer","type":"Cluster","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SequenceViewer",\n"children":[{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SequenceViewer.Sequence_ViewerTitle","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SequenceViewer.Sequence_ViewerTitle","shortname":"Sequence_ViewerTitle"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SequenceViewer.Sequence_ViewerReport","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SequenceViewer.Sequence_ViewerReport","shortname":"Sequence_ViewerReport"}]},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.EmptyPortlet","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Sequence_ResultsPanel.EmptyPortlet","shortname":"EmptyPortlet"}]},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_Facets","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_Facets","shortname":"Sequence_Facets"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Entrez_Clipboard","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Entrez_Database.Entrez_Clipboard","shortname":"Entrez_Clipboard"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_StaticParts","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Sequence_StaticParts","shortname":"Sequence_StaticParts"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Entrez_Messages","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Entrez_Database.Entrez_Messages","shortname":"Entrez_Messages"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.NcbiJSCheck","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Entrez_Database.NcbiJSCheck","shortname":"NcbiJSCheck"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.NCBIFooter_dynamic","type":"Cluster","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Entrez_Database.NCBIFooter_dynamic",\n"children":[{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.NCBIFooter_dynamic.Footer_ExtraData","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Entrez_Database.NCBIFooter_dynamic.Footer_ExtraData","shortname":"Footer_ExtraData"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.NCBIFooter_dynamic.NCBIFooter_dynamic","type":"Cluster","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Entrez_Database.NCBIFooter_dynamic.NCBIFooter_dynamic",\n"children":[{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.NCBIFooter_dynamic.NCBIFooter_dynamic.NCBIBreadcrumbs","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Entrez_Database.NCBIFooter_dynamic.NCBIFooter_dynamic.NCBIBreadcrumbs","shortname":"NCBIBreadcrumbs"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.NCBIFooter_dynamic.NCBIFooter_dynamic.NCBIHelpDesk","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Entrez_Database.NCBIFooter_dynamic.NCBIFooter_dynamic.NCBIHelpDesk","shortname":"NCBIHelpDesk"},\n{"name":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.NCBIFooter_dynamic.NCBIFooter_dynamic.NCBIApplog_NoScript_Ping","type":"Portlet","realname":"EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence.Entrez_Database.NCBIFooter_dynamic.NCBIFooter_dynamic.NCBIApplog_NoScript_Ping","shortname":"NCBIApplog_NoScript_Ping"}]}]}]}]}]};\n--></script>\n<meta name=\'referrer\' content=\'origin-when-cross-origin\'/><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//static.pubmed.gov/portal/portal3rc.fcgi/4189877/css/3808861/3917732/3974050/3751656/3395415/4091728/3257261.css" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//static.pubmed.gov/portal/portal3rc.fcgi/4189877/css/3501913.css" media="print" /><script type="text/javascript">\n\nvar ObjectLinks=[{i:0, ename: "p$ExL", esid:"*", sname: "p$ExL", ssid:"*", dname:"p$el", dsid:"0",m:"CopyValue",p:[],f: function(src, dst) {fn_CopyValue(src, dst);}}]\n\n\nvar ActiveNames = {"p$ExL":1, "EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SequenceViewer.Sequence_ViewerReport.ExpandGaps":0, "EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SequenceViewer.Sequence_ViewerReport.InUse":0, "EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SequenceViewer.Sequence_ViewerReport.ItemCount":0, "EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SequenceViewer.Sequence_ViewerReport.db":0, "EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SequenceViewer.Sequence_ViewerReport.display_type":0, "EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SequenceViewer.Sequence_ViewerReport.fasta_text_params":0, "EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SequenceViewer.Sequence_ViewerReport.maxdownloadsize":0, "EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SequenceViewer.Sequence_ViewerReport.report":0};\n</script></head>\n    <body>\n        <form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" name="EntrezForm" method="post" onsubmit="return false;" action="/nuccore" id="EntrezForm">\n            <div id="maincontent" class="container">\n                <div>\n  <div id="viewercontent1" class="seq gbff" val="3403216" SequenceSize="14415" VirtualSequence=""></div>\n  <div class="hidden">\n    <input name="EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SequenceViewer.Sequence_ViewerReport.db" sid="1" type="hidden" value="nuccore" />\n    <input name="EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SequenceViewer.Sequence_ViewerReport.report" sid="1" type="hidden" value="fasta_text" />\n    <input name="EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SequenceViewer.Sequence_ViewerReport.maxdownloadsize" sid="1" type="hidden" value="1000000" />\n    <input name="EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SequenceViewer.Sequence_ViewerReport.display_type" sid="1" type="hidden" value="single" />\n    <input name="EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SequenceViewer.Sequence_ViewerReport.ItemCount" sid="1" type="hidden" value="1" />\n    <input name="EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SequenceViewer.Sequence_ViewerReport.InUse" sid="1" type="hidden" value="" />\n    <input name="EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SequenceViewer.Sequence_ViewerReport.ExpandGaps" sid="1" type="hidden" value="" />\n    <input name="EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Nuccore.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SequenceViewer.Sequence_ViewerReport.fasta_text_params" sid="1" type="hidden" value="&amp;from=192&amp;to=1684" />\n  </div>\n</div>\n\n            </div>\n        <input type="hidden" name="p$a" id="p$a" /><input type="hidden" name="p$l" id="p$l" value="EntrezSystem2" /><input type="hidden" name="p$st" id="p$st" value="nuccore" /><input name="SessionId" id="SessionId" value="CE8C1A31EBE79081_2023SID" disabled="disabled" type="hidden" /><input name="Snapshot" id="Snapshot" value="/projects/Sequences/SeqDbRelease@1.124" disabled="disabled" type="hidden" /></form>\n    \n\n<!-- CE8C1A31EBE79081_2023SID /projects/Sequences/SeqDbRelease@1.124 portal105 v4.1.r585844 Mon, May 06 2019 02:53:16 -->\n\n\n<script type=\'text/javascript\' src=\'/portal/js/portal.js\'></script><script type="text/javascript" src="//static.pubmed.gov/portal/portal3rc.fcgi/4189877/js/4184195/3217400/4176568/4177091.js" snapshot="nuccore"></script></body>\n</html>'
```

right now, I had all strain IDs and position ranges so I need to copy these DNA sequences for my analysis.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can use `BeautifulSoup` from `bs4` to parse the html and extract the text only

Answer (score 0):

It's a quickly rectifiable error that you have encountered.

What you're doing in basically called "Web Scraping" and to get your desired output, you need to use another package like "Selenium" or "BeautifulSoup".

I personally prefer BeautifulSoup over Selenium but again, that's just my opinion. This is a BeautifulSoup implementation.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/AF061641.1?report=fasta&log$=seqview&format=text&from=192&to=1684'
data = requests.get(url)
content = BeautifulSoup(data.content,"html.parser")
```

This is what some of the finished product would look like. The "content" variable will now have the complete html structure of the webpage. All that's left to do is locate your required information in the html structure and extract from there.

There's just a little left to finish the code but I can't help and finish the code completely because I don't have all the required parameters but you should be able to finish the rest after around half an hour of reading on web scraping.

Hope this helped! :)

Comment: The solution will be more complicated, as OP link only contains some empty div elements probably filled by some sort of JS processing. I don't remember if selenium has a JS engine or not, but as far as I known Beautifoulsoup only help to retrieve and filter the DOM returned by the HTML page